# I have an issue with a firestore query contains next router query value: FirebaseError: where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, next-router

I'm coding an application with the following technologies:

- Next.js
- Firebase

I'm accesing to the router 'query 'property of next useRouter() to make a firebase firestore query. As I'm going to show you later in code, my goal here is to make the compound firestore query with two 'router.query' parameters.

Roughly I'm coding a courses app, so for each lesson's quizzes I want to create them from a dashboard but in a global path, setting only one field with TWO VALUES indicating IN WHICH COURSE AND IN WHICH SPECIFIC LESSON the quiz should be show.

Issue here is that my firestore query is taking the next router query as undefined

Hope one of you can help me with this issue

```
imports
...
const { course, lesson } = router.query

useEffect(() => {
    let unsub

    const q = query(
        collection(firestore, 'quizzes'),
        where("courseName", "==", course),
        where("lessons", "array-contains", lesson)
    )

    unsub = onSnapshot(q, (qs) => {
        ...
    })

    return unsub

}, [course, lesson])
```

On the path "localhost/courses/{course}/{lesson}" my app this throw the following error

> FirebaseError: Function where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined